# How to start a runbook using web service call to SC Orchestrator in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, system-center

I have System Center Orchestrator 2012 R2 and I want to start a Runbook on the runbook server by calling the web service. The orchestrator console works fine if I browse to it like so: http://orchestratorserver.my.domain:82

When I first browse to it I get prompted to enter my domain credentials, only then does the Orchestrator Console page load.

If I call this [PowerShell script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh921685.aspx), I get the following error and I'm wondering if it is related to the credential prompt? There are no firewalls on the orchestrator runbook server, or the host I'm calling from.

```
Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using the module from here.
http://orchestrator.codeplex.com/releases/view/82959